# C# - How to detect if SQLite DB is locked?

Tags: c#, database, multithreading, sqlite

I'm working on a multithreaded C# program that uses SQLite. I'm having a problem that sometimes running SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() to update some rows complains "SQLite error (5): database is locked". I'm aware that this happens because the database gets locked while an insert or update is going on, so if another query to modify the DB comes along the second query will have this database is locked error. So I'm trying to implement workarounds to it, but I'm not sure how I should do it.

I was trying to make it so that if the database locked error is thrown then the program waits a bit and tries again until it works. But somehow no exception gets caught and the code just exits the try-catch block even though the database locked message still gets printed in the debug output. I'm not entirely sure whether the SQL query gets rejected or accepted.

I also tried using TransactionScope and I haven't had the database is locked thing since then, but because of the random nature of the problem I can't be 100% sure if TransactionScope actually solves the problem, or if it only does to an extent, or if it doesn't and I was just lucky so far.

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=DB.db;Version=3;");
connection.Open();
SQLiteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.commandText = inputQuery;
try
{
  command.executeNonQuery();
}
catch (SQLiteException sqle)
{
  Debug.WriteLine("Database error: " + e.Message);
  return false;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  Debug.WriteLine("Database error: " + e.Message);
  return false;
}
finally
{
  connection.Close();
}
```

So I'd really like someone to help me find out 1) how to eliminate the database is locked problem or 2) how to detect if the DB is locked error happens. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend performing all SQLite operations in a single thread using a Producer-Consumer pattern (with either suitable locks, synchronization primitives, or async patterns).

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the safest approach in order to be absolutely free from DB locking.

Answer (score 1):

To detect if Sqlite DB is locked I used approach from [Determine whether SQLite database is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57744538/determine-whether-sqlite-database-is-locked#)
The idea here is to try to acquire lock and release it immediately, if it is not failing then DB is not locked.
The following C# code worked for me:

```
public bool IsDatabaseLocked(string dbPath)
    {
        bool locked = true;
        SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source={dbPath};Version=3;");
        connection.Open();
        
        try
        {
            SQLiteCommand beginCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
            beginCommand.CommandText = "BEGIN EXCLUSIVE"; // tries to acquire the lock
            // CommandTimeout is set to 0 to get error immediately if DB is locked 
            // otherwise it will wait for 30 sec by default
            beginCommand.CommandTimeout = 0; 
            beginCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SQLiteCommand commitCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
            commitCommand.CommandText = "COMMIT"; // releases the lock immediately
            commitCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            locked = false;
        }
        catch(SQLiteException)
        {
            // database is locked error
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }

        return locked;
    }
```

Then when you determined if db is locked you can either wait for it to be unlocked:

```
public async Task WaitForDbToBeUnlocked(string dbPath, CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (IsDatabaseLocked(dbPath))
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), token);
        }
    }
```

or send cancellation message to other thread (via CancellationTokenSource for example) before running your query.

Answer (score 0):

If you're receiving error code 5 (busy) you can limit this by using an immediate transaction. If you're able to begin an immediate transaction, SQLite guarantees that you won't receive a busy error until you commit.

Also note that SQLite doesn't have row-level locking. The entire database is locked. Using a WAL journal, you can one writer and multiple readers. With other journaling methods, you can have either one writer, or multiple readers, but not both simultaneously.

SQLite Documentation on 'SQLITE_BUSY'

Comment: Thanks. What exactly is an immediate transaction? BTW currently I'm using TransactionScope because SQLiteConnection.BeginTransaction() is said to be deprecated, but I'm considering changng back to BeginTransaction since it seems to be the more widely used one.

Comment: Nvm, I found out the BEGIN IMMEDIATE. This will definitely help me since I can implement the keep trying algorithm for the BEGIN IMMEDIATE portion. However I'm not sure on how to use BEGIN IMMEDIATE from C#.