# WPF, Send Messagebox to inform user that DataBase is locked

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I've created an app in C# .Net WPF. This app uses an sqlite database, but this database is shared with other programs.

So rarely my app and the others are running simultaneously, and more rarely they attempt to write in db simultaneously.. And All apps are crashing at this point...

So, I want to patch my app to wait that db isn't locked anymore before doing something with it.
I've been thinking about making a dirty try/catch loop with a number of attempting, but it seems to me to be a too dirty way (and waste of ressources)

The other program has a visual indicator when it uses db, so I've thought that a solution can involve user action. When database is locked, a MessageBox open to notify the user to wait until other program has finished before click ok and continue.

Is it a way to test if the database is locked without try/catch?

Comment: I think "nagging" the user with something he doesn't need to do anything with only press the button for a retry. I'd rather go for the "dirty" try/catch loop with a maximum reties.

Comment: Yes, I haven't precised : The user can turn off the other program which is mainly in fault, It make db verifications, so they can be quick or long depending cases; if verification is restarted later it made no differences.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  You just have to try and see what happens.  But, if you're interacting with your DB correctly, the wait should never be long, therefore a simple retry pattern should effectively hide the problem from users.  If for some reason it does take a long time, just bail out and offer a message.

Comment: Thanks for your point of view; but I still maintain that I haven't access to the faulting program that use the db. And duration of his use is very chaotic. Yes an other way is forcing killing this app in mine before mine use the db. However, we are still in dirty ways.

My point, is that try/catch method isn't a good practice and I attempt to avoid it, in this special case User action seems to be preferable, but I haven't knowledge about a way to test if locked without try/catch.

Comment: Trying to open a file stream and catch any `IOException` is a perfectly fine solution to your issue. Handling expected exceptions is not a "waste of resources".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comments, I tried a try/catch method. I'm still not convinced that this is the cleanest method, because I don't like the idea of ​​waiting for an exception. An expected exception cannot be an exception in my opinion.

Maybe someone will come up with a solution that doesn't use this subterfuge, but I haven't found a better match for my expectations.

Thank you for your comments.

```
using SQLite;
public bool IsDatabaseLocked(string dbPath)
    {
        bool locked = true;
        using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
        {

            try
            {
                connection.Execute("BEGIN EXCLUSIVE");
                connection.Execute("COMMIT");
                locked = false;
            }
            catch (SQLiteException)
            {
                // database is locked error
            }
        }
        return locked;
    }

    public void WaitForDbToBeUnlocked(string dbPath)
    {

        int i = 0;
        while (IsDatabaseLocked(dbPath))
        {
            i++;
            if (i > 10)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please release manually Database or wait");
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

My answer is inspired by the following questions:
[C# - How to detect if SQLite DB is locked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47256792/c-sharp-how-to-detect-if-sqlite-db-is-locked)